# while allocating/printing why don't I have to dereference an array pointer in c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int *i = (int *) malloc(12);
    *i[0] = 1;
    printf("%d", *i[0]);
}
```

`i` is supposed to be a pointer. So then why doesn't this code work?

and why does this code  work?

```
void main(){
    int *i = (int *) malloc(12);
    i[0] = 1;
    printf("%d", i[0]);
}
```

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook and read the explanation of what the `[]` operator does, does your C++ textbook's explanation answer your question? Can you explain, in your own words, what "`*something[0]`" means, and how you believe this expression works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not following any textbooks. You got any book recommendation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: To start with: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) If you follow that advise, the compiler will point the 3 severe bugs/syntax errors in your code that makes this program invalid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add index operator "[]" after a poitner - you are telling the compiler "Hey, take this pointer, then do pointer arithmetic on it with the value within the [] bracets, and dereference the address it points to".

Saying it with other words - when you add index operator "[]", your pointer gets treated as regular variable, and does not need additional dereferencing operator. It's already dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

`i[n]` *is* a dereference.  Equivalent to `*(i + n)`.

`i[0]` has type `int` so you cannot dereference it: `*i[n]` is equivalent to `**(i + n)`, and is invalid.

Comment: And `*( &i[0] )` would be valid (the `*` and `&` canceling out).

Answer (score 0):

> Why this code don't work?

```
    *i[0] = 1;
```

`i` is a pointer, so `i[0]` considers it (the pointer) to be a pointer to the start of an array, obtain the element at position 0 (the one you should assign) and assign it a 1 value.  If you try to dereference it again, as the array element itself is not a pointer (but an integer value) you will get an error from the compiler.  What you want to do is to use the array element itself

```
    i[0] = 1;
```

For the same reason, to print the array element, you need to use `i[0]` again and not the expression you used.

Why is this done with `malloc()`? Malloc is a general purpose dynamic memory allocator, it gathers a continous block of memory to fit the size you specify and returns to you a pointer to the result.  You can then use that pointer as the address of the array you want to handle, or as a structure to be filled up with data.... etc.  The `void *` pointer that `malloc()` returns can be converted to any other pointer type, making it flexible for any purpose.